# How can I send UDP data in Deno?

Tags: udp, deno

I've tried using the following code in my `measure.ts` script:

```
Deno.DatagramConn.send(...)
```

When I run my script like this: `deno run --unstable --allow-all measure.ts` I get the following error:

```
Property 'DatagramConn' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'. 'Deno.DatagramConn' is an 
unstable API. Did you forget to run with the '--unstable' flag?
```

This error seems to simultaneously deny and confirm the existence of the `Deno.DatagramConn` API

Similarly I've tried

```
Deno.connect({transport : 'udp'})
```

but this gives me the follow error (which probably makes sense as UDP is 'connectionless'):

```
Type '"udp"' is not assignable to type '"tcp"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I seem to have figured it out. I actually need to first `listen` on a socket, and then send data on it.

```
const addr : Deno.NetAddr = {transport: "udp", port: 8125, hostname: "1.2.3.4"};

const socket = await Deno.listenDatagram({
        port: 0,
        transport: "udp",
        hostname: "0.0.0.0"
       });
  
socket.send(new Uint8Array(), addr);
```

It's easy when you know how  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`